# How to implement interface of portable or net standard library Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms you can implement in each platform that you require an interface that you define in a portable class or most recent .net standard dll.

Let's suppose that I have a library that have implementations in Android, iOS but not in UWP or WPF.
Is there a way to implement interface in platform-specific code even if I don't have source code of that dll?

Comment: Hi , what's meaning of no having source code ,you can share detail scenary here to discuss . If own a library to reference , I think it's possible to do .

Comment: Could you show in terms of code what you are trying to achieve? Plus, this could be an [XY-Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is the exact issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have a package called "Xamarin.Essentials" that contains a "Secure Storage" feature in net standard. The problem is that library doesn't support this feature in WPF platform or GTK+. I could understand why, because there is no a standard way provided by the SO or Framework to do so like in Android or iOS, or even UWP. In that case I don't have choice to implement myself to workaround this.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT In the case of Xamarin.Essentials there is source code available, but I have other cases where I use custom controls of a external provider that only have their nuget package

Comment: @Mr_LinDowsMac Okey , it can not use the nuget from other platform unless you have the source code to generate the special nuget for current platform.